# Why is my app still displaying old code after generating new app?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I deployed my app like a month ago, and everything was working OK.
In the meantime my app changed a lot so I decided to deploy new version.
I used command `git push heroku deployment:master` (git branch deployment is containing some files just for deployment).

When I opened my app via `heroku open` I noticed that my app is still using old home page. After Googling around I've tried:

- `heroku reset`
- Creating new branch and pushing new code with few test lines added
- Try to clear cache, open pages in different browsers
- Checking the files with `heroku run bash` (all files are as they should be)

I went even further and tried:

- `heroku apps:destroy`
- `heroku create` (created new project, and used `git push heroku deployment:master` again)

Event after accessing the new URL, there is still old code, old .html pages and everything. I'm using `Node.js v8.11.4` 
Help me out please! Thanks in addition.

EDIT: Was trying also to `git clone` Heroku Git URL, to my desktop. All files are as expected, I have no idea, where is heroku getting old files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of fooling around and trying a lot of different things there were 2 things that I need to do.

1. Don't forget to run `ng build` before deploying new version of app, or else old public files will be deployed
2. Clear the build cache for an app using the following commands:

   `heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
    heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
    git commit --allow-empty -m "Purge cache"
    git push heroku master`

Where `appname` is replaced by the name of the app you want to clear the cache for.

SOURCE: [How to clear build cache](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache)

Comment: Didn't work for me, but `heroku restart` did ([as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4241916/4964553)), where the Heroku Dynos are restarted.